# How can I install packages hosted in a private PyPI using setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I'm trying to write the `setup.py` install file for a private project, which has both public and private dependencies. The public ones are hosted on PyPI, whereas the private ones are hosted on a server running [simplepypi](https://github.com/steiza/simplepypi).

I would like both public and private dependencies to be resolved and fetched during installation.

I thus added my dependencies to `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires = [
        # public dependencies
        'argparse==1.2.1',
        'beautifulsoup4==4.1.3',
        'lxml==3.1.0',
        'mongoengine==0.8.2',
        'pymongo==2.5.2',
        'requests==1.1.0',
        'Cython==0.18',
        # private dependencies
        'myprivatepackage1',
        'myprivatepackage2'
    ],
    dependency_links=['http://pypi.myserver.com/packages'],
    ...
)
```

I build the package tarball using the command `python setup.py sdist` and install it in an activated virtualenv using `pip install --verbose path/to/tarball.tar.gz`.

However, the pip log lines do not mention my private PyPI server anywhere, and https://pypi.python.org/simple/ seems to have been queried twice.

```
Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///home/b/code/mapado/mypackage/dist/mypackage-0.5.1.tar.gz
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/mypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Downloading/unpacking myprivatepackage (from mypackage==0.5.1)
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/myprivatepackage/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (myprivatepackage does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/myprivatepackage/ when looking for download links for myprivatepackage (from mypackage==0.5.1)
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/myprivatepackage/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (myprivatepackage does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/myprivatepackage/ when looking for download links for myprivatepackage (from mypackage==0.5.1)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement myprivatepackage (from mypackage==0.5.1)
Cleaning up...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

it looks like you didnt specify your host like the doc of [simplepy](https://github.com/steiza/simplepypi) said you need to setup your `~/.pypirc` with the good hostname like

> To use it run "simplepypi". You can upload packages by:
>
> [...]
>
> Not using twine yet? Here is the legacy way of uploading Python packages (not recommended):
>
> **Modify your ~/.pypirc so it looks like:**
>
> ```yaml
> [distutils]
> index-servers =
>     pypi
>     local
>
> [local]
> username: <whatever>
> password: <doesn't matter, see above>
> repository: http://127.0.0.1:8000
>
> [pypi]
> ...
> ```

then you'll upload your package on it

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r local
```

and could install it from there

```
pip install -i http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi <your favorite package>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I fixed it! My mistake was that, as you pointed out, I needed to add the ``"http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/"`` URL to ``dependency_links``. **Warning**: it needs to be ``"http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi/"`` and not ``"http://127.0.0.1:8000/pypi"``, as the latter returns a 404.

Comment: Can I do this _without_ modifying `~/.pypirc`?  That is, just purely through `setup.py`?

Comment: Downvoted because the question is about `setup.py`. Modifying `~/.pypirc` is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

`dependency_links` is ignored by default (at least in pip 9.0.1)

In order for it to reach out to your sever you need to add `--process-dependency-links`

I believe [pip 10 will bring a new mechanism](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3939#issuecomment-341998365), but for now this has got it working for me

I also had to update `dependency_links` to include the package name, for example:

```
dependency_links=[
    "http://internal-pyp:5678/simple/your_package_name"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make your package as a normal pip package and publish it to the private repo. To install it, you can specify global option `--extra-index-url`  in the [config file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file):

```
$ cat ~/.pip/pip.conf
[global]
extra-index-url = https://...
```

Comment: Be aware of the dependency confusion attack opened by the use of `extra-index-url` here.